# Using Vue Router disables jquery when switching back and forth links

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am using vue router for my navigation. I have multiple pages including a home and about us page. I have some jquery written in another JS file for my home page that works perfectly fine, however when I click on my about us page and then go back to my home page the script stops working. This also applies to when I go to another page and then back to my home page. I have a feeling this is due to my vue router. The jquery script is as follows:

```
$('.arrow_down').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.ourservices').offset().top
    }, 600);
});
```

And my vue router looks like:

```
// Define some components
var home = Vue.extend({
    template: '#home-template'
})

var aboutus = Vue.extend({
    template: '#aboutus-template'
})

var portfolio = Vue.extend({
    template: '#portfolio-template'
})

var contact = Vue.extend({
    template: '#contact-template'
})

// The router needs a root component to render.
// For demo purposes, we will just use an empty one
// because we are using the HTML as the app template.
// !! Note that the App is not a Vue instance.
var App = Vue.extend({})

// Create a router instance.
// You can pass in additional options here, but let's
// keep it simple for now.
var router = new VueRouter({
    hashbang: false,
    history: true,
    linkActiveClass: "active"
})

// Define some routes.
// Each route should map to a component. The "component" can
// either be an actual component constructor created via
// Vue.extend(), or just a component options object.
// We'll talk about nested routes later.
router.map({
    '/': {
        component: home
    },
    '/aboutus': {
        component: aboutus
    },
    '/portfolio': {
        component: portfolio
    },
    '/contact': {
        component: contact
    }
})

// Now we can start the app!
// The router will create an instance of App and mount to
// the element matching the selector #app.
router.start(App, '#app')
```

Feel free to ask for additional information.

Comment: How are you including the jQuery and in what order are these scripts? Also instead of using the demo var App where you extend with an empty object you could just give the vue-router a component which houses your jQuery. Any console output bytheway?

Comment: My jQuery comes before my Vue script. No console output or error messages. Is it possible to give me an example of how I can house my jQuery in a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your script inside components ready function:

```
var home = Vue.extend({
  template: '#home-template',
  ready: function () {
    $('.arrow_down').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.ourservices').offset().top
      }, 600);
    }); 
  } 
})
```

Refer sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tsuqmzhL/23/

Also refer Vue Instance Lifecycle https://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram